# RadEditor posts empty in firefox

Tags: asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, telerik, radeditor

I'm building a composite control that uses the telerik ajax controls as it's inputs, now the RadComboBox and RadTextBox were working fine, keeping state and returning edited values however the radeditor was posting an empty string everytime. Here's the clincher, it only happens in firefox, in IE the RadEditor works exactly as is expected and posts it's text. Has anyone come across this before and is there a solution to get around this as I can't guarantee my users won't be using Firefox?

Forgot to mention, the RadEditor is inside an updatepanel.

Comment: is there any code you can post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following KB article: http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/editor/radeditor-content-not-saved-after-ajax-update-in-firefox.aspx

If you are manually submitting the page using client code (e.g. form.submit() in JavaScript) you might need to call the saveContent() method from the RadEditor client API. This will make sure the editor HTML will be sent along with the rest of the posted data.